# While checking whether a string minimum 5 digits, no alpha nor special characters gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check whether a string contains a minimum of 5 digits, no alphabets or special characters.
My code is as follows:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]{5,}$/g;
```

But when I tried with `prm= "5653636*"` or `"32266"` or `"256"`

it always returns `false`
when I do the following:

```
re.test(prm)
```

Comment: When using `test`, do not use `/g`.

Comment: What's wrong with `^\d{5,}$`?

Comment: Additionally you could even do the (perhaps more ugly?) hack of trying to convert it to a number and checking that it is larger than 10000. Although that would eliminate leading zeroes.

Comment: Try `^([^a-zA-Z\d]*\d){5,}[^a-zA-Z]*$`

Comment: My question is why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

To see if a string doesn't have an alphabet `[^a-zA-Z];`
^ -means NOT and [] is used to match range of characters
and u can use **length** property to find the length.

The following snippet will match is a string doesn't have an alphabet and it has its length is greater than 5.

```
var _string  =  "1234567";
var re       =  /[^a-z]+/i;

if(re.text(_string)){ // true
}

if(_string.length > 5){ //true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that I got your requirements right, I think this is what you're looking for:

`[^a-zA-Z]{5,}`

- At least 5 characters
- No alphabetical characters (A-Z)
- Numbers, special characters and white space are allowed

If you want to allow the special characters from your regex only, you can do:

`[0-9!@\#\$%\^&\*\)\(\+=\._-]{5,}`